# How does stock ownership registration work

Tags: stock-exchanges, shares

How does stock ownership/registration work intraday?

To give an example, if a hedge fund buys 100 shares on an exchange and later in the day sells them on a different venue such as a MTF or dark pool, how is the exchange informed that they have sold those shares on a different venue and cannot sell those shares back on the original exchange?

What system of record is used to verify that someone actually holds the shares that are being sold?

Comment: Investors and traders place orders which then go  on the order book.  If a trade is  executed, the exchange notifies broker who notifies the client and the order is removed from the order book.  We live in an electronic era and  registration is handled by it, regardless of the holding period (which is determined by the owner of the shares).

Comment: Ok but who stores the record of the fact that the broker owns the shares? That broker has to buy the shares from another broker/market participant?

Comment: The transfer agent.  See: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/transferagent.asp